# hdfs: command not found

Tags: linux, hadoop, command, hdfs, centos7

I am using Centos7 and Hadoop 3.2.1. I have created a new user in Linux. I copied the .bash_profile file from the master user to my new user. But when I try run hdfs commands I am having the following problem:

```
bash: hdfs: command not found...
```

[the error i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTlJm.jpg)

I think I did something missing about the new user. But I don't know what it is.

And I do not know what can I do now. Could you help me?

Answer (score -1):

*I solved the problem myself. It's about permissions.*

Make sure your user's bash_profile file is the same as your other user's bash_profile file. Then log in as root and run this command:

```
chmod -R 777 /home/hadoop/
```

By doing this, you gave permission your $HADOOP_HOME directory. Now log in with your new user again and try run hdfs commands, for example: hdfs dfs -ls /

So you can do anything what you want in new user. When your done, revoke permissions you gave.

**SO DON'T SHUT DOWN YOUR SERVERS. EVER AND NEVER. NOT YET. Run this code as root:**

```
chmod -R 700 /home/hadoop    
chmod -R 660 /home/hadoop/.ssh
```

**If you don't, you won't start your namenodes and datanodes. Because the permission of the subfolder cannot be more than or equal to the parent folder. And it will be a big problem to fix.**

So that's all, and it's worked for my case. Now i can run hdfs commands on my new user. I hope I could help.